# Bad dua on boss?

Tags: dua

Skip to last paragraph if you dont want full story

I am apprentice today i did my last exam and told my boss that after friday im leaving as the course has finished he said he will rong and find out, but college was closed. So instead he ohoned my dad saying i always miss days and dont complete my work. My dad came home and said this to me. My mun defended me by saying i do go as my mun and dad drop me off. And i always finish my work on time and i do the most as i am only one in three of his employee that works 4 days a week 9-5. Also i worked for him for free for 7 months and he said he would pay me and he didnt now dince october he bas payed me bellow minuim wage in uk, way too low i was supposed to get 3.40 an hour for 40 hours a week, but instead got paid £8 a day. Die to this i always wore the same clothes everday since december, i couldnt afford anything as my mum and dad didnt want to give me moneh and i never asked them for money since age 13 now im 18. I am the only one from my group of friends that wears the same clothes everyday. And doesnt cut his hair. Also due to my pay my parents have had fights and neraly got divorced as my dad works in famiky and my uncle pays him 700 a month for 11 hours a day for 5 days.

Because he paid me £8 a day and my work hours it was hard for me to get exercise and go gym and my liver has gotten week and i have been ill. My boss talks bad about all of the people who worked before me as they left due to him being very stingy.

Now he goes i cannot leave until june. I have done self harm in the past due to this life syle i cannot contiue this. He has wronged me woth money and my health and loed to my dad.

Can i lawfully give him baddua?

Answer (score 1):

You can't give anyone a bad dua. Mohammad PBUH never gives a bad dua to any of his friends before they convert to Islam even tho they are at war. The best way is that you pray for your boss to be lead by Allah in the right way so that he might realize his/her mistake

Answer (score 0):

The right question should be:

Can I, **from an Islamic perspective**, make a bad Du'a against him?

## The short answer:

Yes, you can though not exactly **bad** Du'a.

## The long answer:

If you feel that someone has done anything unfair to you (such as treated you unequally, judged you wrongly), then you have three choices to choose from:

> 1- Ask Allah to take back your rights...

Ask Allah to take back your rights from him and to punish him in the real world before the afterworld. Knowing that the Du'a from a person who is wronged is guaranteed to be fulfilled. But you should be careful to not make a Du'a to deal with an injustice behavior with a greater injustice.

*This is an unpreferable solution*

> 2- To wait till the Final Judgment Day...

To wait till the Final Judgment Day to take his Hasanat till they meet your need (based on what he did to you in the real world). If their Hasanat became none (finished), then you give him your Sayi'at so he will end up in Hell.

This requires patience, and as Allah Almighty (said in [Surah Az-Zumar (39) — Verse 10](https://quran.com/39/10):

- In Arabic (the exact wording):

> اِنَّمَا يُوَفَّى الصّٰبِرُوۡنَ اَجۡرَهُمۡ بِغَيۡرِ حِسَابٍ...

- In English (in what it means):

> Indeed, the patient will be given their reward without account.

*This is a better solution than the first one*

> 3- To completely forgive him...

To completely forgive him which is a hard decision to make but the one with most benefits to gain because Allah Almighty will reward you with Hasanat more than you would get if you took from that unfair person whether you went to the *First* choice or the *Second* one.

*The best solution among them*

---

For reading further about this topic, [see here](http://aboutislam.net/counseling/ask-about-islam/can-make-dua-someone/)

[Source: A Youtube video in Arabic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EOFEdipGbDI)